# How to use only a few struct members from structs to create a new packed struct in c?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to decode some data received from Matlab and I need a struct something like this:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) struct1{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) struct2{
    int a
}

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct{
    int struct1.a;
    int struct1.b;
    int struct2.a;
    int struct1.c;
}
```

What is the best way to get this packed struct so that I can decode the data from Matlab? I don't think C would let me create mystruct without objects of struct1 and struct2.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The simplest (and for your specific example most probably best) way is member-wise copy. If there is sufficiently large overlapping sub-structures, you could define sub-sructs and copy those in a single assignment - will most probably not end up mach faster or more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The struct you intend on using doesn't have to have other structs defined.  Just define the fields you need with the types you need:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) mystruct{
    int struct1_a;
    int struct1_b;
    int struct2_a;
    int struct1_c;
}
```